# Meteor - Model Inheritance

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, schema.org

What is the syntax for creating inheritance in models (specifically MongoDB models created with `new Meteor.Collections`)?

I am trying to model some of the schemas found on http://schema.org, and I would really like to use inheritance to allow me to model them accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking into this, but the docs now support this kind of thing. From the docs:

```
// An Animal class that takes a document in its constructor
Animal = function (doc) {
  _.extend(this, doc);
};

_.extend(Animal.prototype, {
  makeNoise: function () {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
});

// Define a Collection that uses Animal as its document
Animals = new Mongo.Collection("Animals", {
  transform: function (doc) { return new Animal(doc); }
});

// Create an Animal and call its makeNoise method
Animals.insert({name: "raptor", sound: "roar"});
Animals.findOne({name: "raptor"}).makeNoise(); // prints "roar"
```

Answer (score 1):

The inheritance model you will use depends on the type of data that you're gonna store in the collections. If classes not gonna differ a lot you can put all of them in one collection and add `_type` field that would store information about child class.

You can also create collections for each child classes and one collection for storing relations.

I think that in most cases the first approach is much faster and easier to implement.

You can use Meteor Astronomy package for creating such model definition https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy